# Problems updating Worklight to FP1 (6.1.0.1) on WAS 7

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

We have upgraded Worklight Server to 6.1.0.1 via IBM Installation Manager and it shows as successfully updated. However, the Worklight Console still shows 6.1.0.0

**WAS 7.0.0.31**

About:

- Server version: **6.1.0.00.20131126-0630**
- Project WAR version: **6.1.0.01.20140311-2356**
- Adapter name: xxxxxxx. Version: **6.1.0.01.20140311-2356**
- Application name: xxxxxxxx. Version: **6.1.0.01.20140311-2356**

Any ideas on what may be wrong?

Comment: Did you deployed your WAR again after updating your Server?

Comment: screen shot? I would double-check the way you've deployed your project's war file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server install appears to be corrupted and fixpack not really applied (although installation manager says it was). The console war file had nothing to do with this problem.

On a separate server, the identical war file was deployed and shows the server at the correct level.

Answer (score 1):

Worklight console is nothing but your WAR. Re Deploy your WAR which is build from 6.1.0.01 and check again.

Comment: Could you please share the screen shot of worklight console version?

Comment: you can `Update the project's WAR file of a deployed Worklight Server configuration` for more info see this [link](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html)

Comment: Thanks, I think it is possible that the person who upgraded the server needs to follow those additional instructions to upgrade the server configuration. Thanks for the link.